# OData call with multiple parameters- URI format?

Tags: odata, breeze

How to call the breezeController with multiple parameters?
I have defined two methods:

```
public IQueryable<Test> Tests()

public IQueryable<Test> Tests(int type, bool Tests)
```

The uri used for the call is : Odata\Tests

To call the one with parameters, how should the parameters be specified?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want, the request url or the breeze code to generate the url?

Comment: Consider marking the correct answers in your questions as such to help future visitors - you will probably also get more help when you ask new questions : )

Comment: Have you resolved this? Any solutions?